# Webview not displaying text in proper format in android

Tags: android, webview

I am showing html file from assests folder in to Webview  in android. It is not showing properly.  Here is image of webview [image], But when I open that html file in crome broswer that is displaying properly. Here is image of browser

[image]

Below is my code

```
 WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
```

Below is code that contains html file

```
<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;
margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:13.5pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-ideograph;text-indent:-13.5pt;line-height:normal'><b><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>83-</span></b><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>I</span><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Kruti Dev 010"'> vkSj </span><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>O</span><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Kruti Dev 010"'> f=Hkqt </span><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";color:black'>ABC</span><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Kruti Dev 010"'> ds Øe”k% var%dsUnz vkSj
ifjdsUnz gSaA c&lt;+kbZ xbZ js[kk </span><span style='font-size:10.0pt;
font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>AI, </span><span style='font-size:10.0pt;
font-family:"Matura MT Script Capitals"'>&#8710;</span><span style='font-size:
10.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>ABC </span><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Kruti Dev 010"'>ds ifjo`Ùk dks fcUnq </span><span
style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>D</span><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Kruti Dev 010"'> ij izfrPNsfnr djrh gSA
;fn <span style='position:relative;top:5.0pt'><img width=121 height=23
src="img_1.png"></span>vkSj <span style='position:relative;
top:4.0pt'><img width=71 height=21 src="img_2.png"></span>rks<span
style='position:relative;top:13.0pt'><img width=53 height=40
src="img_3.png"></span></span><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;
font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";color:black'>CGL Tier - I - 2013  Evening</span></b></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;
margin-left:1.5in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-ideograph;
line-height:normal'><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>   
CGL Tier - I - 2013  Evening Set - 2 (21 - 04 - 2013)</span></b></p>

<p class=MsoListParagraph style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:
0in;margin-left:13.5pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:justify;text-justify:
inter-ideograph;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:
"Times New Roman","serif"'>(a) 3                                                  (b)
1</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormalCxSpFirst style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:
0in;margin-left:27.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:-13.5pt;line-height:
normal'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>(c)
2

                                                  (d) 4</span></p>
```

How can we show webview like browser image?
Here is also link that contains html file [html file link](http://13.232.122.107/Divine/resources/demo.html)

Comment: Add this `webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");` to show hindi characters correctly

Comment: are you sure that images are in assets in same folder next to `demo.html`?

Comment: @BAHMAN After implemntaion of webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8") is not working

Comment: @BAHMAN did not used any images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this : (After add required fonts in assets folder)

```
  String head="<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'Kruti Dev 010';src: url('file:///android_asset/krutidev.ttf');} " +
                "@font-face {font-family: 'Times New Roman';src: url('file:///android_asset/timesnewroman.ttf');}" +
                "@font-face {font-family: 'Matura MT Script Capitals';src: url('file:///android_asset/maturasc.ttf');}" +
                "body {font-family: 'Kruti Dev 010';}</style></head>";
        String HtmlString = "<html>"+head+"<body>"+containet()+"</body></html>";
        //myWebView.loadData(HtmlString, "contentType=text/html", "charset=UTF-8");
        myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",HtmlString,"text/html","utf-8",null);
```

where containet() return your HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");` to show hindi characters correctly

make sure that images are in assets in same folder next to `demo.html`

for example one of imags src is `src="img_3.png"` if it is in folder `assets/images` you have to change it to `src="images/img_3.png"`

Comment: After implemntaion of webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8") is not working and did not used any images. All content is displaying using html file